# A net in a product space and its cluster point

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, product-space, nets

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$ be two topological spaces. And let $Z=X\times Y$ be the product space equipped with the natural product topology $\mathcal{T}_Z$ on $Z$. Then, let $\{z_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a net in $Z$ such that $\{\pi_x(z_\lambda)\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ and $\{\pi_y(z_\lambda)\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ are nets that have cluster points $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, respectively, where $\pi_x$ and $\pi_y$ are the natural projections from $Z$ onto $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Now, can somebody give an explicit example of a net $\{z_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ (and topological spaces $X$, $Y$, and hence $Z$) that satisfies the above condition, but $(x,y)\in Z$ is not a cluster point of the net?

Thank you.

Comment: Take sequences, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, say. Distinguish between even and odd indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and the sequenece $\{(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
n&\text{if } n\text{ is odd}\\
0& \text{else}
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_n=\begin{cases}
n&\text{if } n\text{ is even}\\
0& \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ah, that simple;;; Thanks